# How to set animation time of keyboard

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview, keyboard

Hopefully a basic question: Is there a simple way to change the speed with which the keyboard pops up? I can do this in my ViewDidLoad method:

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.5];
```

And it will not only influence the speed with which my keyboard pops up (dead slow), but also all other animations, like the cursor animation (also dead slow). Is there a way to target the speed of the keyboard alone? `[UIView.firstResponder setAnimationDuration:2.5];` doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I actually need this:

```
// Get the duration of the animation.
NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
[animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

// Animate the resize of the text view's frame in sync with the keyboard's appearance.
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

textView.frame = newTextViewFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I found this in Apple's sample code illustrating how to add a bar on top of the keyboard. But I'm still slightly confused as I read somewhere else that the animationDuration is read only. Anyway, this works, so I guess that this is the answer to my question.